# Visualising a mixed effects model

Tags: r, mixed-models, multi-level

So as the title suggests I would like to visualise these two models that I have in order to better understand their relationship. The first one is a fixed slope model and the second one is a random slope model. I would like to plot them both separately but I don't know how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
mlm1 <- lmer(trstplt ~ c_gini_2019 + (1 |atchctr), data = ESS)
         
mlm2 <- lmer(trstplt ~ c_gini_2019 + (c_gini_2019 |atchctr), data = ESS)
```

Examples of data:

```
> head(ESS$c_gini_2019)
[1] 27.5 27.5 27.5 27.5 27.5 27.5

> head(ESS$atchctr)
<labelled<double>[6]>: How emotionally attached to [country]
[1] 10  9 10 10 10  8

Labels:
 value                           label
     0 Not at all emotionally attached
     1                               1
     2                               2
     3                               3
     4                               4
     5                               5
     6                               6
     7                               7
     8                               8
     9                               9
    10       Very emotionally attached

> head(ESS$trstplt)
<labelled<double>[6]>: Trust in politicians
[1] 5 3 5 3 7 5

Labels:
 value           label
     0 No trust at all
     1               1
     2               2
     3               3
     4               4
     5               5
     6               6
     7               7
     8               8
     9               9
    10  Complete trust
```

```
head(ESS)

# A tibble: 6 × 7,904
  ess9_id  cntry ess9_…¹ regunit nuts1 nuts2 nuts3 name  essro…²
  <chr>    <chr> <chr>   <dbl+l> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>   <dbl>
1 AT00000… AT    AT22    2 [NUT… AT2   AT22  ""    ESS9…       9
2 AT00000… AT    AT21    2 [NUT… AT2   AT21  ""    ESS9…       9
3 AT00000… AT    AT33    2 [NUT… AT3   AT33  ""    ESS9…       9
4 AT00000… AT    AT21    2 [NUT… AT2   AT21  ""    ESS9…       9
5 AT00000… AT    AT32    2 [NUT… AT3   AT32  ""    ESS9…       9
6 AT00000… AT    AT21    2 [NUT… AT2   AT21  ""    ESS9…       9
# … with 7,895 more variables: edition <chr>, proddate <chr>,
#   idno <dbl>, nwspol <dbl>, netusoft <dbl+lbl>,
#   netustm <dbl>, ppltrst <dbl+lbl>, pplfair <dbl+lbl>,
#   pplhlp <dbl+lbl>, polintr <dbl+lbl>, psppsgva <dbl+lbl>,
#   actrolga <dbl+lbl>, psppipla <dbl+lbl>, cptppola <dbl+lbl>,
#   trstprl <dbl+lbl>, trstlgl <dbl+lbl>, trstplc <dbl+lbl>,
#   trstplt <dbl+lbl>, trstprt <dbl+lbl>, trstep <dbl+lbl>, …
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

I've tried to plot them but can't seem to get them to work

Comment: What do you want to vizualize exactly

Comment: @YacineHajji sorry I know I should have been more specific. I don't know how to interpret the regression output so I was just hoping I would be able to plot it so I can interpret what the regression is actually telling me. Ideally I would just like to plot the predictions for each of the 11 rows for atchctr with regression lines across the graph that has c_gini_2018 on the x-axis and trstplt on the y-axis. And then do it again with random slopes to see the difference. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the `lmer4::lmer` in `summary` then `plot` the regression lines by abstracting the intercept and slope from `mlm$coefficients` and putting them in `abline`. Since your data weren't in a reproducible format, I made some up (`sales` and `price` by commodity ID) to run the models.

Models

```
mlm1 <- summary(lme4::lmer(sales ~ price + (1 | id), data = df))
mlm2 <- summary(lme4::lmer(sales ~ price + (price | id), data = df))
```

Plot

```
plot(df$price, df$sales,  
     ylim = c(2000, 2700), xlim = c(11, 22), 
     col = "black", pch = 19, bty = "n",
     xlab = "Price", ylab = "Sales")
abline(a = mlm1$coefficients[1,1], b = mlm1$coefficients[2,1], lty = 1)
abline(a = mlm2$coefficients[1,1], b = mlm2$coefficients[2,1], lty = 2)
legend("topright", 
       c("Random Intercept", "Random Slope + Intercept"), 
       lty = 1:2, bty = "n")
```

[image]

Data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 
13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 
17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18), price = c(12L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 
14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
17L, 18L, 19L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 20L, 21L, 22L), sales = c(2550, 2575, 
2300, 2450, 2375, 2425, 2500, 2500, 2600, 2400, 2450, 2625, 2675, 
2377, 2350, 2415, 2425, 2475, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2425, 2400, 2475, 
2525, 2375, 2400, 2410, 2160, 2175, 2215, 2150, 2175, 2190, 2205, 
2100, 2200, 2250, 2265, 1975, 2115, 2150, 2050, 2025, 2025, 2015, 
2000, 2015, 2050, 2035, 2025, 2035, 2070)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-53L))
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried to plug it in and this came out:
> mlm1 <- summary(lme4::lmer(trstplt ~ c_gini_2019 + (1 | atchctr), data = ESS))
> mlm2 <- summary(lme4::lmer(trstplt ~ c_gini_2019 + (c_gini_2019 | atchctr), data = ESS))
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues

Comment: plot(ESS$c_gini_2019, ESS$trstplt,  
+      col = "black", pch = 19, bty = "n",
+ abline(a = mlm1$coefficients[1,1], b = mlm1$coefficients[2,1], lty = 1)
+ abline(a = mlm2$coefficients[1,1], b = mlm2$coefficients[2,1], lty = 2)
Error: unexpected symbol in:
"abline(a = mlm1$coefficients[1,1], b = mlm1$coefficients[2,1], lty = 1)
abline"
> legend("topright", 
+        c("Random Intercept", "Random Slope + Intercept"), 
+        lty = 1:2, bty = "n")
Error in (function (s, units = "user", cex = NULL, font = NULL, vfont = NULL,  : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
>

Comment: Your model didnt converge, that doesn't have anything to do with the plotting aspect of this though

Comment: Also this is a base R plot, not `ggplot` so doesn't use `+`